# Authorization and Authentication in microservices - the good way

Tags: oauth-2.0, architecture, microservices, openid-connect

I'm considering a microservice architecture and I'm struggle with authorization and authentication. I found a lot of resources about `oauth2` and `openid connect` that claim they solve the issue but it is not clear enough for me.

Let's consider we have a following architecture:

[image]

In my system I want to add a feature only for a certain `group` of users defined by `role`. I want to also know the `name` of the user, their `email` and `id`.

After my research I find the following solution to be a good start:

1. SPA application displays `login form`.
2. User fills in the form and sends `POST` request to `authN&authZ server`.
3. The server replies with `access token` (being a `JWT`) that contains `name`, `email`, `id` and `role` of the user. The response contains a `refresh token` as well.
4. SPA application stores the token and attaches it to every request it makes.
5. `Microservice 1` and `Microservice 2` check if the token is valid. If so, they check if the role is correct. If so, they take user info and process the request.

How far away from the good solution I am? The login flow looks like `Implicit flow with form post` described [here](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/implicit-flow-with-form-post) but with implicit consents and I'm not sure if it's fine.

Moving forward, I find passing user data in `JWT` (such as `name`, `email`) to be not a good solution as it exposes sensitive data. I found resources that say it is recommended to expose only a reference to a user in token (such as `ID`) and replace such token with a classic `access_token` in `reverser-proxy`/`api gateway` when sending a request to a microservice. Considering such solution I think that following scenario is a good start:

1. SPA application displays `login form`.
2. User fills in the form and sends `POST` request to `authN&authZ server`.
3. The server replies with `access token` and `refresh token`. API gateway (in middle) replaces `access token` with `ID token` and stores claims from access token within its cache.
4. SPA application stores the token and attaches it to every request it makes.
5. Handling a request, `API Gateway` takes `ID Token` and based on the user ID generates a new `access token`. The access token is send to microservice 1 or microservice 2 that validate it as previous.

How do you find such solutions? Is this a secure approach? What should I improve proposed flow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should consider making your cluster private and utilize api gateway as the only publicly exposed api which handles all of your auth. Your auth should be first line of defense. Before your microservices.

Comment: Have you considered using the BFF pattern? https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf

Comment: @exceptionsAreBad thanks for answer. Of course the microservices should be in a private cluster and API gateway is the only publicly exposed api. I hope the diagram I put in my question presents it. API Gateway is responsible for handling auth as well. My question is more about how to handle the auth.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks for the answer. Yes, I was considering using the BFF pattern but in my question it doesn't matter it the external API component is API Gateway or BFF. In my example there is only one client so actually API Gateway is BFF.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right tracks:

**ZERO TRUST**

This is an emerging trend, where each microservice validates a JWT using a library - see [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/zero-trust-overview/). JWT validation is fast and designed to scale.

**CONFIDENTIAL TOKENS FOR CLIENTS**

Internet clients should not be able to read claims that APIs use. The swapping tokens in a gateway concept is correct, but the usual approach is to issue opaque access tokens here, rather than using ID tokens. At Curity we call this the [Phantom Token Approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/).

**SECURE COOKIES IN THE BROWSER**

One area to be careful about is using tokens in the browser. These days `SameSite=strict HTTP Only` cookies are preferred. This requires a more complex flow though. See the [SPA Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/) for some recommendations on security.

SPAs should use the  code flow by the way - aim to avoid the implicit flow, since it can leak tokens in the browser history or web server logs.

**SUMMARY**

All of the above are general security design patterns to aim for, regardless of your Authorization Server, though of course it is common to get there one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Phantom Token sounds really useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use your own login form. As Garry Archer wrote, use the auth code flow with PKCE which is the [recomended flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) for applications running in a browser.

If you don't want to get an ID token, don't ask for the `openid` scope in the initial auth request. The type of issued access tokens (JWT or opaque) can often be configured on your OAuth2 server. So I see no need to issue new tokens at your gateway. Having more token issuers opens more ways of attacking your system.

Your backend modules can use the [userinfo endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo), which will give them info about the user and validate the token. This way, if the token was invalidated (e.g. user logged out), the request processing will not proceed. If you validate just a JWT signature, you will not know about the token being invalidated.

If you plan to make requests between your backend modules as part of of a user request processing, you can use the original access token received from your SPA as long as your modules are in a safe environment (e.g. one Kubernates).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm thinking about own login form. I consider e.g. an e-commorce application built as a microservice system. It contains its own auth server. I do not want to use 3rd part providers such as Facebook. In such a case it sounds reasonable to me to implement own login form, just send a request for a token to auth server (via gateway) and simply get access and refresh token in response. Even if the client is a SPA. Such solution proposes Chris Richardson in his book about microservices . Does it make sense for you or I'm missing something?

Comment: Using your auth server login form has usually few advantages, which may or may not be relevant for you. Users usually trust the auth server more than your application (it probably passed some security audit). If your application processes user's credentials, you are responsible for them not getting compromised. Another thing is a possibility to use Single Sign On. The last thing that comes to my mind is a possibility to easily use more complicated auth mechanisms, such as 2nd factor auth that may be available out of the box.